# Keeping page content loaded upon closing the window in Electron

Tags: javascript, browser, electron

What I'm trying to achieve is "real" app-like behaviour in a sense that when I close the app on MacOS (hit X, so the app is still in dock) and afterwards open the app from dock again, the webpage content should be there immediately. As I'm trying to build a container for a web-app, the behaviour I'm getting is that every time I open the app, the web page is loaded again causing friction in the UX.

I've tried some dirty workarounds, like calling .hide() on main window from the renderer process before unloading the window:

```
const {remote} = require('electron');
const main = remote.require('./main.js');

window.onbeforeunload = e => {
  main.hideWindow();
  e.returnValue = false;
};
```

and in main process

```
exports.hideWindow = () => {
  mainWindow.hide();
};
```

But that way I cannot quit my app at all.

Another option I considered was to load the whole mainWindow DOM in the memory, then upon opening the app, in the `<webview>` [preload script](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#preload) load the cached content into the webview and once the page loads, overwrite the webview content, but it also seems very hackish.

I know Slack behaves exactly how I want my app to behave, but I'm struggling to find how they achieve that instant-load (or perhaps not ever closing, except when Quit is selected from the Dock or Cmd+Q is hit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having a flag which governs the "closing" behaviour

```
let allowQuitting = false;
```

and handling the closing like this

```
function quitApp() {
  if (app) {
    allowQuitting = true;
    app.quit();
  }
}
function closeApp() {
  if (mainWindow && !mainWindow.isDestroyed()) {
    mainWindow.hide();
  }
}
```

On closing, I listen on closing events

```
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    closeApp();
  });

  mainWindow.on('close', event => {
    if (allowQuitting === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      closeApp();
    }
  });
  ...
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

On activating, I first check if the window exists

```
app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  } else {
    mainWindow.show();
  }
});
```

The app can be closed using Cmd+Q due to the accelerator:

```
const template = [{
  label: 'Application',
  submenu: [
    ...
    {
      label: 'Quit', accelerator: 'Command+Q', click: () => quitApp()
    }
  ]
},
...
];
Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(template));
```

This gives me the desired result, albeit with a side-effect. The app can be closed with Cmd+Q, **but can't be closed from the dock** (by selecting Quit) or when shutting the system down (says it interrupted the shutdown).

Comment: I have the same problem, and wanting exaclty the same behavior without the side-effect. Slack app does it and i'm trying to investigate that...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly then I think there are a couple of standard workarounds for this. Specifically around

> ...not ever closing, except when Quit is selected from the Dock or
>   Cmd+Q is hit)

```
// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

And...

> open the app from dock again, the webpage content should be there
>   immediately.

```
app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, you have outlined the behavior of the quickstart app, which results in reload of the page upon app activation, the phenomenon I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Sorry perhaps I misunderstand then, if that is the code which results in the phenomenon you are trying to avoid then surely you are doing something similar...and need to remove it. No?

Comment: Well the problem is that the window is closed (same as closing the browser). Upon opening it, the `createWindow()` is called and the webview loads the page again, causing a brief delay in accessing the application. I would like to get rid of that delay either by caching the application content or somehow working around closing the window and instead just hiding it.